# Is there a XPath with schema equivilent for JSON?

Tags: json, jsonschema, jpath

Is there a library that provides a way to query JSON that is similar to XPath **with a schema?**

I say with a Schema because we want typed queries both for the filtering (inequalities on dates) and the returned values.

We need this on Java and would like to have it on .NET.

Yes there are a couple of JPath implementations I have found, but none that use a schema. There are several JSON schema validators ([this appears to be the most widely used](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)). But it does not tie to any JPath implementation.

What I'm looking for is a combination of the two. So that on a query I get the result back properly typed. And this also allows handling dates as dates and you can then do inequalities on them.

**Update - please re-open:** This is marked as a duplicate but the linked to "duplicate" is a solution that does not use a schema. We need a schema for the reasons enumerated above.

Comment: What platform? It's interesting that you added the tag `jpath` to this question - https://www.npmjs.com/package/JPath

Comment: @Adam - updated. Need Java and .NET is very nice to have.